# Is there any way to declare variable type for class name?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to declare an array variable, but I didn't know what the type is this.

```
MyApp.MainPage
```

I'll use it for my array type.

```
public static class[] MyArray = {MyApp.HomePage, MyApp.SettingsPage};
public MainPage(){
  this.InitializeComponent();
  Frame.Navigate(typeof(class[0]));
}
```

How to declare it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's really what you are talking about, but it seems you want an array of `Type` instances:

```
public static Type[] MyArray = {typeof(MyApp.HomePage), typeof(MyApp.SettingsPage)};
```

and use it like that:

```
Frame.Navigate(MyArray[0]);
```